# core data entity to custom NSManagedObject class

Tags: core-data, entity, subclass, nsmanagedobject

I have a simple Entity "Products" with attributes:

```
id int64
sku text
descript text
quantity int64
unitPrice Decimal
totalPrice Decimal
```

What i need is the value of totalPrice to be result of quantity + totalPrice

To do so i need probably to use subclass of NSManagedObject instead of Entity.
I generated such a class from the Entity but i don't know how to implement the class.
I want to ADD, REMOVE SET and GET records.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface Products : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * descript;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * quantity;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * sku;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDecimalNumber * totalPrice;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDecimalNumber * unitPrice;

@end


    #import "Products.h"


@implementation Products

@dynamic descript;
@dynamic id;
@dynamic quantity;
@dynamic sku;
@dynamic totalPrice;
@dynamic unitPrice;




@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just implement `totalPrice` as a transient property. Mark it as **transient** in the Core Data model editor.

Then, in your managed object subclass, just override the getter.

```
- (NSNumber*)totalPrice {
   return @(self.unitPrice.floatValue * self.quantity.intValue);
}
```

If any of the other two attributes are not set it should return 0 as expected.

Comment: Thank you.But i'm wandering wether i should use both in same time the Entity in core data and the subclass?Now with the code above i can't add and remove.I connected the ArrayController with the subclass instead of the model in core-data and it doesn't work.

Comment: What you describe is a different problem. You should first accept the answer and maybe formulate a new question.